# create_captcha - function returns false - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my directory structure:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
$data['msg'] = $msg ;

$this->load->helper('captcha');

$captcha = array(
    'word' => rand(9999,99999),
    'img_path'  => './captcha/',
    'img_url'   => base_url().'/captcha/',
    'font_path' =>  './captcha/font.ttf',
    'img_width' => '130',
    'img_height'=> 50,
    'expiration'=> 5800
);

$cap = create_captcha($captcha);
$data['image'] = $cap['image'] ;
echo var_dump($cap);
return;
```

but my output returns `bool(false)`.

Comment: According to `captcha_helper` code there're several cases when `false` returned. You have to debug the code by yourself.

Comment: Try with full image path i.e. `'img_path' => FCPATH.'captcha/',`.

Answer (score 1):

There's two possibilities here. Either you don't have the GD extension installed (if you're on a apt - enabled Linux-environment, try `apt-get install php-gd` or `apt-get install php7.0-gd` (depending on your PHP - version) or ask your hosting provider about it) or your font path `'font_path' =>  './captcha/font.ttf'` is incorrect. Double check them both.

Answer (score 0):

This works if the directory structure exists [WEB_ROOT]/img/captcha/:

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
$this->data['captcha'] = create_captcha(array(
    'img_path'      => dirname(FCPATH) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'img'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'captcha'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'img_url'       => '/img/captcha/',
    'font_path'     => APPPATH . SYSDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'fonts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'texb.ttf',
));
```